# Volt: Accessing store collection in component's config/initializers/boot.rb file

Tags: ruby, voltrb

I am trying to access the store collection in a component's config/initializers/boot.rb file to declare some middleware to blacklist an array of IP addresses. Unfortunately I am getting an error of:

```
#<NameError: undefined local variable or method `store' for main:Object>
```

Is it possible to access the store collection here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
Volt.current_app.store
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. For some reason, I can access the page collection by using "Volt.current_app.page" but not the store method.

Comment: Ok, indeed, the StoreRoot is present, but I couldn't access any data. Maybe you should move your logic to a different file and run it with `volt runner`, it won't be when the server start but might be the only way

Comment: That could be one way to do it. I can't even access the StoreRoot from Volt.current_app

Comment: Are you on volt 0.9.4? If you're not you might try the `$store` global.

Comment: I am using volt 0.9.4.pre4. Also $store just returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
$page.store.sub_collections
```

works correctly.